# Why would selling a thousand copies of a book get a bestseller rating?

Tags: historical-context, georgian-language, lasha-bugadze, the-literature-express

Zaza's first published book sold a grand total of 400 copies. He was informed by his editor that books need to sell at least 1000 copies to get a bestseller rating.

Why was that enough sales to be considered a bestseller?

Comment: When? Where? What genre/format of book? Which bestseller chart?

Comment: @StuartF The book is set in Georgia and was copyright in 2009. The book doesn't indicate which bestseller list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d be surprised how few book sales it takes to get a bestseller rating. Graham Greene was able to quit his job at the *Times* on sales of 3000 copies of *The Man Within* (although that was a rather different time with lower living expenses relative to income—contemporary authors who sell 3000 copies won’t be quitting their day jobs). Lani Sarema got to the top of the *New York Times* bestseller list in 2017 by buying¹ 5000 copies of her book. I would imagine that in the context of Georgian book sales, 1000 copies would be a large number of sales.

---

1. As I recall, she didn’t even have to actually buy the books, but rather placed preorders of books at bookstores who report to the *New York Times*. Each preorder was something like 19 copies which was just short of the threshold where the order would be considered a bulk order and wouldn’t count for the *New York Times* list.